# Realizar validação no formulário somente após perder o foco no angular validator

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou utilizando as validações dos formulários reativos no angular, coloquei uma validação de e-mail válido, o problema é que enquanto o usuário ainda está digitando o email já aparece o . Gostaria de saber como fazer pra só mostrar a mensagem de erro após perder o foco no campo de e-mail.

Atualmente meu código é esse:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required formControlName="email" matInput placeholder="Email">
    <mat-error>
        Você precisa entrar com um e-mail válido.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**TS:**

```
this.formularioLogin = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
  password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
});
```

**ErrorStateMatcher:**

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, voce deve fazer o codigo ser ativado no evento OnBlur e nao no OnClick/OnKeyPress como atualmente esta ocorrendo.

Voce tambem pode usar o **.debounce** para efetivamente postergar a validacao.